# If I shouldn't use functions within my Angular template, why does it seem to be okay to use formControl .get()?

Tags: angular

I am a bit confused about when it is/isn't okay to use functions within an Angular template.

I've seen in many places within the Angular documentation that they use functions like `.hasError` or `.get` from the reactive forms module within the template.

Why isn't this a concern?
If `.get` and `.hasError` isn't a concern, is it okay to use things like `.includes` within the Angular template as well?

This is a bit of a tangent, but I'm trying to use the `[checked]` property on a checkbox, and the straight forward way would be to call `Array.includes` within the `[checked]` attribute, but I assume this is incorrect? How else can I do it without having to store a bunch of redundant variables? Would the correct approach be to create an `includesPipe`? If so, why isnt this something that is built into Angular?

Comment: Who says that this is not correct?

Comment: Who says what is not correct? Using .includes within the template? I've read in many many places that you should never use functions within the Angular template, as mentioned in my question

Comment: It's about heavy computation functions. Because the change detection tries to compare old values with new values, whenever "the value" is obtained by calling a function, this function will be called on every detection cycle. If your function take ages to complete, your UI becomes junky. For blazing fast evaluating functions, this effect is negligible.

Comment: The default change detection strategy implies that change detection is called pretty often, so even though your function *may not seem that heavy*, it might induce rendering slowness because how often it is called. You can still use functions in your templates, but if you notice any rendering issues, consider changing the change detection strategy to `OnPush`, or try to run some operations outside *the zone*.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu So its not a strict rule that you should NEVER use functions within the template? Its just that you need to be careful of putting expensive functions in the template? I've seen articles even saying that you shouldnt have a function that just calculates fullName() by adding first and last name. Thats obviously not an expensive function. Do you believe that using such a function in the template is fine?

Comment: @CraigArmstrong such function is fine but useless, you can do it directly in the template.

Comment: You can always try it out. Use the browsers dev tools and if the performance matches your expectations it's fine to use.

Comment: @CraigArmstrong Try to call a function that does a `console.log` before returning the value and you will see how often it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it depends on the function.

Say you have those two functions :

```js
lightFn() {
  return true;
}

heavyFn() {
  for (const x of new Array(1000).fill(0)) console.log('hey');
  return false;
}
```

The light function has 1 instruction, the heavy function has *at least* 1000 instructions.

When you start using Angular, the change detection is ran very often (almost everytime you move your mouse).

This leads in a lot of function calls.

If your function is light, then it's not an issue. Taht's why you can for instance use getters, or built-in function like `control.hasError`.

THat's why people say to not use functions in templates : it's easier than explaining everything. I do it myself with newcomers, unless like you, they ask for explanation.

There are several solutions to be able to use heavy functions directly in HTML :

- Use the `onPush` change detection : change detection gets reduced A LOT, hence you do much less function calls
- Use a pipe : pipes are pure at first, this means they are ran only when the input provided to it changes. Just be sure not to trigger it too often !
- Use some state management : The heavy computation is only ran when the state changes, and your template does not have to call the heavy function at every change detection.
- Simplify your code : most of the time, you do not have to call a heavy function into your template. This is a good exercise to improve your overall code quality and your issue resolving skills. By far my most appreciated one !

Helping all of this helps you, if not, feel free to ask for more information !